# regex replace [ with \[

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write a regex in Ruby that will add a backslash prior to any open square brackets.

```
str = "my.name[0].hello.line[2]"
out = str.gsub(/\[/,"\\[")

# desired out = "my.name\[0].hello.line\[2]"
```

I've tried multiple combinations of backslashes in the substitution string and can't get it to leave a single backslash.

Comment: You might be confusing the escape sequence for the character. Within quotes as a string literal, backslashes will need to escaped: `"my.name\\[0]"`. When that value is printed without quotes, then only a single slash should be rendered: `my.name\[0]`

Comment: Yes, that is what was happening... I was only looking @ the output (and not "puts out")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression here.

```
str = "my.name[0].hello.line[2]"    
puts str.gsub('[', '\[')
# my.name\[0].hello.line\[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it worked correct:

```
str = "my.name[0].hello.line[2]"
out = str.gsub(/\[/,"\\[")
puts out  #my.name\[0].hello.line\[2]
```

If you replace `puts`with `p` you get the inspect-version of the string:

```
p out  #"my.name\\[0].hello.line\\[2]"
```

Please see the `"` and the masked `\`. Maybe you saw this result.

As [Daniel already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478216/676874): You can also define the string with `'` and don't need to mask the values.

Comment: +1 for a full explanation and for pointing out his solution did actually work.